# Acer Aspire RTC/CMOS battery location

Tags: bios, battery, acer-aspire

TL;DR Where is the RTC/CMOS battery of the Acer Aspire 1410 located?

I have an old Acer Aspire 1410 which I want to use (Don't ask why :) ). The problem is that it throws an error when started only on battery. In fact two errors - 251 and 271. If one make changes in the BIOS, everything is OK. Unfortunately the problem arise again on next boot on battery power. The model is exactly like this - https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Acer+Aspire+1410+Disassembly/9199
Pictures of the disassembled laptop - https://imgbox.com/gallery/edit/XL7iO5OJhP/wpyCC83ncniLTtIu

Answer (score 1):

The CMOS battery of the Acer Aspire 1410 is located on the back of the
motherboard. This requires a quite serious disassembly of the laptop,
which is better carried out by a professional.
The battery is also inside a plastic frame that can easily break.

You can see how to disassemble the computer in the video
[Disassembly acer aspire 1410 & fan cleaning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDnUJNmhqRA),
although this is not the main purpose of this video.

Here is a picture taken from time-frame 5:16 :

[image]

The battery-housing itself will look like :

[image]

I repeat that disassembling is hard and putting it all back
together correctly is harder, so is better done by a professional.

Comment: Hi, harrymc! Unfortunately I can't see the battery on my laptop motherboard. Please see the images above in my original post (those at https://imgbox.com/) to get an idea of the actual condition.

Comment: Your photos don't look similar to those in the video. It doesn't look at all like it's the same model. I start thinking that the deleted answer by @Tetsujin is correct and there is no battery.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Better undelete your answer, as it might be the correct one.